# How to handle user permission based authorisation using Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I want to allow my users to view some parts of the web application depanding on there rights (editable by users with a specific permission in the application).

Consider a User entity with hasAccessToView1, hasAcessToView2,... boolean attributes.

How can I configure Spring security to be able to use Spring Security tags in my jsps to display something if the corresponding boolean property in the user is set to true ?

I also need to authenticate my users from a ldap server before retrieving the corresponding user from the database.

I guess I will need a custom Authentication provider.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security [supports LDAP out of the box](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html). Probably, all you need to do is to write some xml configs and tune your code a bit.

[Spring Security's EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) can help you to solve access problems.